# Why is my PromQL queries not merging in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have two metrics of type count:

```
metric1(instance="", instance_ip="")
metric2(instance="", instance_ip="")
```

I'm having troubles when I try to display both on Grafana via table:

- Query:

```
v A
  Metrics: metric1_total + 0
v B
  Metrics: metric2_total + 0
```

Note: I added 0 to remove `__name__` in the column

- Expectation:

```
time           instance         instance_ip    Metric1 Value    Metric2 Value
Jan-1-2020     0.0.0.0:8000      0.0.0.0             1                2
```

- Reality:

```
time           instance         instance_ip    Metric1 Value
Jan-1-2020     0.0.0.0:8000      0.0.0.0             1   
[ instance, instance_ip, Metric2 Value                       v ]
NOTE: ^--> This is a dropdown in Grafana
```

Grafana isn't automatically merging the values of metric1 and metric2.

Comment: What version are you on? Have you tried the merge transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

1. Click on the "Transform" tab
2. Click on the "Add transformation" button
3. Choose "Outer join" option
4. Fill the "Field name" field with "instance"

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at the wrong way for merging my values.